# Why my GPS always returns position of Africa in Android?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get the curret position of my phone, **I do not need the last position know of teh device**.
The follow code get the latitude and longitude of my phone but always return data of Africa

**onCreate**

```
 Double latitude, longitude
    LocationManager mLocation;
    String bestProvider;
    LocationListener mListener;
    mLocation = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mListener = new MyLocationListener();
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    c.setBearingRequired(false);
    c.setCostAllowed(false);
    c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    bestProvider = mLocation.getBestProvider(c, true);
    mLocation.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, mListener);
```

**Inner Class**

```
        class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            latitude = location.getLongitude();
            longitude = location.getLatitude();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


        }
    }
```

This code always return `0.0643404`,`2.6465832,7`. How is wrong??

---

I 've been test my aplication on many devices and happen the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens sometimes when you have an invalid gps point, or invalid latitude/longitude points. The map with then plot that data into it's default error point which is most likely in the middle of the map.

This has happened to me with ArcGIS Ersi maps.

Comment: I am experiencing weird problem, I am not getting 0.0, 0.0 as lat lng. I am getting non zero lat, lng from africa, where as i am in asia.

Answer (score 0):

On the device, check under the `Settings` then `Developer Options` and lastly `Allow mock locations`

How to get into developer options is known to change with different versions of android, you may [Google for it](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20access%20developer%20options).

Comment: I'll have to do that in all devices with the application, rigth?

Comment: Your post didn't indicate how many devices the problem was occurred on, so I assumed it was just your development device.  If this is happening on more than one machine, then it is unlikely that `mock locations` is the cause.